# Do I need to create an appid for each of the web api's hosted on IIS? Under what circumstances will i need to use a separate appid?

Tags: iis, app-id

I am creating several asp.net core web apis. I will be hosting them in IIS. Do I need to create an appid for each of the web api's hosted on IIS? doesn't IIS run under a default user account? Under what circumstances will i need to use a separate appid?

Comment: Could you share which app id you are talking about? and iis run under the default windows user login account.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I meant creating a service account for each one of the apps i host in IIS on the same server

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

IIS generally use the application pool identity to run the application pool. you do not need to create a service account every time for each application pool.

"virtual accounts" that allows IIS to create a unique identity for each of its application pools.

just make sure to use different application pools for different iis sites.so the application problems in one application pool do not affect other Web sites or applications.

when you create a site in iis it ill automatically create new application pool with the same name as the site.

For more detail you could refer this below link:

[Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

[Service Accounts Step-by-Step Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd548356(v=ws.10))

[Application Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/)